# How to remove source from RSS feed?

Tags: views, feeds

I have a site where Drupal generates rss through a view and then an external source uses that rss. Now the client says that I should remove the source from RSS. How can I remove the source from rss? See the source in image. 
The source shows the url.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom template taking views-view-rss.tpl.php as starting point.
See the template under modules and views/theme/views-view-rss.tpl.php